# Prove that $\mathbb S^1/\partial \mathbb S^1\cong\partial \mathbb S^2$.

Tags: general-topology

I denote $$\mathbb S^1=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$$ and $$\mathbb S^2=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1\}.$$

We denote $\mathbb S^1/\partial \mathbb S^1$ the space obtained by gluing the boundary of $\mathbb S^1$. I have to prove that 
$$\mathbb S^1/\partial \mathbb S^1\cong \partial \mathbb S^2$$
i.e. that $\mathbb S^1/\partial \mathbb S^1$ is homeomorphic to the unit sphere of $\mathbb R^3$. [You can see a picture here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology))

How can we proceed ?

Comment: I think your notation is a little confusing/unusual.  Normally $S^n$ means the $n$-sphere, i.e. the boundary of the $(n+1)$-ball $B^{n+1}$.

Comment: not to me...  :-)

Comment: Fair enough!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism, it's not too difficult to prove a 'First isomorphism theorem': if $X$ is a compact space, $Y$ a Hausdorff space, and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ a continuous map, then $X/ \sim$ is homeomorphic to the image of $f$ (with the subspace topology from $Y$), where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation $x_1 \sim x_2 \iff f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.  The easiest way to prove this is with the universal property of the quotient topology (which is well worth getting to grips with if you're not already familiar with it).

Now take $X$ to be the closed disc, $Y$ to be the $2$-sphere, and $f$ to be your favourite map wrapping the disc over the sphere and crushing the boundary to, say, the north pole.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's a good answer (and I didn't think using this result). But is it possible to prove it algebraically ? i.e. to describe the quotient and construct the homeomorphism.

Comment: @idm: For an explicit map, how about take tangent of the radial coordinate to expand the unit disk to the whole plane, and then stereographic projection of the plane onto the sphere

Comment: You mean give the map $f$ explicitly?  One way would be to use a homeomorphism from the open unit disc to the whole of $\mathbb{R}^2$, say $z \mapsto z/(1-|z|^2)$, and then compose with the inverse of stereographic projection from the north pole.  Define $f$ to send the boundary of the disc to the north pole itself.

Comment: Ok, very nice :-)